# Why I get Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics?

Tags: android, bitmap, fatal-error, recycle

I have 4 activities A, B, C and D.

Activity A has a menu. One of its options opens Activity D which has a list view.
Activity A opens Activity B by a button. Activity B opens Activity C by a button.

Activity C has 4 ImageViews that I recycle them on finish.

When I do the following scenario every thing is OK:

A -> B --back to--> A --click Menu to go to D --> **OK**

When I do the following scenario I get this fatal exception:

A -> B -> C –back to--> B --back to--> A --click Menu to go to D --> **get exception**

There is no relation between Activity D and C. but why I get this exception here????

```
A->B->C (using buttons)

A-> D (using menu)
```

---

```
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@41326810
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1038)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1142)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:393)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:924)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10983)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3223)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2092)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3218)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11088)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3398)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10986)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10986)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2126)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-15 11:33:49.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I noticed I should not use same image resources for different Activities while one of them is recycling its bitmap.**

I was using same image resource (img01.png) for ImageViews in both Activity C and Activity D.

I changed the image resource of Activity C to img02.png and problem solved.

But I do not know its logical reason.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you backed out of an activity doesn't mean it's gone.  If you're going to recycle bitmaps, make sure they aren't in use. You could set the `ImageView` to have a different (perhaps blank) `Drawable` when you recycle the bitmap.

Comment: I noticed that I am using same default image from resources for Activity C's images and Activity D's images. when I removed that resource from D's ListView problem solved. Why?